# Working shell command doesn't alias

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, alias

I can run,

```
 svn status |grep -v .jasper$ |cut -d ' ' -f8 |sed '/.*\..*/!d' |xargs ls -altr --color=auto
```

just fine. But when I go to add this as an alias (alias svtr="...") I get an error saying...

```
-bash: !d': event not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using backslash `\` to escape your `!` should work.

```
alias svtr="svn status |grep -v .jasper$ |cut -d ' ' -f8 |sed '/.*\..*/\!d' |xargs ls -altr --color=auto"
alias svtr
alias svtr='svn status |grep -v .jasper$ |cut -d '\'' '\'' -f8 |sed '\''/.*\..*/\!d'\'' |xargs ls -altr --color=auto'
```

Actually, that just eliminates the error, because inside `""` the shell tries to interpret `!`.

you may want to revert quotes (i.e., use singlequote to define alias, and use doublequote inside the aliased command, and escape singlequotes where necessary.

Comment: Thanks! The second solution worked after I removed the escape character in front of the !.

Answer (score 2):

The `!d` in your `sed` command is causing this, because `!` is the Bash history expansion character.  Temporarily turn off history expansion, like this:

```
set -H
alias svtr="..."
set +H
```

That should do it.

Comment: I tried this and received the same error.

Comment: Sorry, but it works for me.